# Send variable from template to view (looking for alternatives?)

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views, modelform

So my view sends a list of objects to my template which dynamically creates one form for each object (with unique IDs in the template). When one of the forms is submitted, I want my view to know exactly which one sent the POST request.

I thought about using session storage to write the form id, but other posts on SO have shown me why that's a bad idea. Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Right now my template says something like:

```
{% for object in objects %}
 {% include form %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I access `object.id` for a given `form` in the view in a way other than cookies? Or are cookies okay?

Comment: You should use formsets for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: That seems like an improvement to the way I create the HTML forms, but i don't really see how it helps me access the ID of the form. Right now my template says something like: 

{% for object in objects %}
 {% include form %}
{% endfor %}

Using formsets would I be able to access object.id inside the view?

Comment: Ah, got it. Why don't you include a hidden field in each form that contains a 'form_id'? Then, when one of your forms processes, your view could check that field to determine which form was filled out.

Comment: Well I am using not using custom forms right now (ie, `{form.as_p}`) so sorry for not just testing this suggestion out -- but if I put a hidden field it still needs to save to the database right? Seems just as wasteful as saving a cookie, plus the clutter it adds to my db

Comment: No, a field in your form does not need to save to the database. You can use it to process the form within views.py without putting it in your models (or saving to any database).

Comment: Thanks, it's working! This is cleaner than cookies for sure!